# unistd.h constants linux x86_64

Tags: c, linux

If I printf `__NR_exit` in a simple program on 64 bit linux,the value is 60 as defined in `<asm/unistd_64.h>`. However, this code (compiled with -nostdlib) segfaults:

```
void _start(){
 asm("movl $60,%eax;"
     "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
     "int $0x80");
}
```

But, this runs as expected:

```
void _start(){
 asm("movl $1,%eax;"
     "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
     "int $0x80");
}
```

where `__NR_exit` is defined as 1 in the 32 bit version of `<unistd.h>`

Clearly 1 is the correct constant. Why are the 32 bit syscall values being used?

```
$ uname -a                                         
Linux galois 3.14.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 8 10:08:38 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

The calling convention on x86-64 systems is different. Linux adopted the System V ABI, which includes its calling convention.

The syscall number is stored in `%rax`, and arguments follow in `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, `%r10`, `%r8`, and `%r9` in that order, and the `syscall` instruction is used instead of `int $0x80`. Only integers and items categorized as belonging to the `MEMORY` class may be passed, and only those registers may be used. Items of class `MEMORY` are passed via the stack. You may only pass 6 arguments or less to a syscall.

User-mode functions are called using the same registers with the first function argument being stored in `%rdi`, except that `%rcx` is used instead of `%r10`, and `%rax` is used to indicate the number of SSE arguments passed rather than a syscall number.

See [System V AMD64 Calling Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) for more information, but a more definitive guide on some Linux-specific information can be found in subsection 2.1 of Appendix A in [the actual specification](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html).